# Pycharm does not accept "list[Example]" as type hint for list of items

Tags: python, python-typing

I found a weird type hinging in PyCharm:

[image]

`Example` is my own class. But I guess this is less important because the IDE is complaining about `list` type does not define `__getitem__` method which is no true. I'm wondering if it's a bug or I used it in a wrong way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [official PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) to denote list of objects you should use `typing.List`, not `list` builtin.

```
from typing import List


class Something:
    pass


def f(seq: List[Something]):  # no warning
    for o in seq:
        print(o)
```

Update January 2021:

Please note that built-in generics were implemented in Python 3.9, as described in [`PEP585`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/).

Comment: Good to know. Even the official docs has a non-compliant example of `list[float]`! https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: `list[float]` started to be supported in Python 3.9.

Answer (score 4):

Łukasz explained how to correct your code. I'll explain why the error message says what it does.

`list` defines `__getitem__`, true, but that isn't what the error message is complaining about. The error message is saying that `type` itself, which is the `list` *type's* type, doesn't support `__getitem__`. For `list[whatever]` to be valid, `type` would have to define a `__getitem__` method, not `list`.