# Pycharm and Django TypeError for request.GET[value]

Tags: python, django, pycharm

This is more of an annoyance than a real problem, but when using the following code:

```
if request.method == "GET":
    device_id = request.GET['id']
```

The request.GET has the following error:

> Class 'type' does not define '**getitem**', so the '[]' operator cannot be used on it's instance.

A really great description of the problem (although in a different situation) can be found here:

[Pycharm: Type hint list of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735843/pycharm-type-hint-list-of-items)

I am simply trying to get rid of the PEP errors in PyCharm without disabling them. Any thoughts on how to change the above code?

Thanks!